# How to uncomment multiple lines of code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I did a ctrl K + ctrl C (adds `//` to a line) on a lot of lines of code that I need uncommented. What is the quick key method to uncomment code in Visual studio?

Comment: When in doubt, check the menu item itself. The keyboard shortcuts are listed in the right margin.

Comment: **Is there an uncommenting solution when commenting shorthand is used? I used "/* ... \*/"** and VS 2019 automatically adding a "*"to each new line created in the section. Sadly, not a single one of the options below or the Right Click menu seem able to quickly uncomment this section. Obviously, deleting the first and last comment block characters didn't work either.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> removes the `//` comments

Comment: CTRL K + C adds the comments back

Comment: In my Visual Code
Ctrl + C,  add comments
Ctrl + C again, remove coments

Answer (score 26):

I believe it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

There is also a button for it on the Standard toolbar.

Answer (score 5):

ctrl + /
can be used for adding and removing comments.

Answer (score 3):

Try  + U or click the little icon on the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Resharper, there is a much nicer alternative:

> *just* **`right Alt + /`** for both

By using this single shortcut, you can simply toggle between commenting/uncommenting code, without having to remember/switch between two shortcuts for each.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + K + C (to comment) and Ctrl + k + U (to uncomment the code)

Or

or use Ctrl + / (for the same)

Answer (score 2):

Qwerty: `Ctrl + /`

Azerty: `Ctrl + :`

Comment: This comments, but won't uncomment.

Comment: it does both for me

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add, that in the latest version of VS, `ctrl + u` makes it caps. They instead made it a toggle command, so it is actually just `ctrl + k` again to make it uncommented.

Answer (score 1):

I have the german keyboardlayout.
VSCode-x64-1.52.1
**To leave a comment:**
You have to highlight the code, then push
Ctrl + #
**or**
Ctrl+K, stay at Ctrl and push C

**to commen out:**
Ctrl + #, it toggles on/off the comment
**or**
Ctrl + K, stay at Ctrl and push U

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a bit different. It is ctrl-shift-C to comment and ctrl-shift-alt-C to uncomment.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the default settings? I am also using VS Community 2017, but that shortcut opens the class view window for me. And code commenting is accomplished through the same method that the OP uses.

Comment: As far as I know I am using the default settings. I haven't changed any macros.

I am using it to developer for Unity so perhaps the Unity plugin changed the default settings?  Not sure why that would be though.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Q alternates between comment and uncomment. 
Unfortunately Ctrl K Ctrl U does not work in few environments, rather it adds instead of removing. My case on windows, using composer file I faced Ctrl K Ctrl U not working.
I m using VS Code, ver 1.36.1

links to all keys short cuts: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 0):

In Visual C++ 2019 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> both comments and uncomments.

Answer (score 0):

italian keyboard uncomment: Ctrl + ù

Answer (score -1):

Windows: Shift+Alt+A  is a toggle.  Simply choose your lines of code you want to comment out then  Shift+Alt+A,  then simply choose your lines of code you want uncomment and then Shift+Alt+A.

Comment: Shift+Alt+A toggles comments in Visual Studio Code, not in Visual Studio. These two are completely different applications.